# Why use HttpMethod.POST instead of HttpMethod.GET in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, android, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

In [Udacity Developing Scalable Apps with Java course](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud859/l-1219418587/e-1497718593/m-1497718594), some API methods of the backend application (that conceptually should be [HttpMethod.GET](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/ApiMethod.HttpMethod)) are implemented using [HttpMethod.POST](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/ApiMethod.HttpMethod).

The following comment is found at the Java documentation:

```
/**
 * Normally this kind of method is supposed to get invoked by a GET HTTP
 * method, but we do it with POST, in order to receive conferenceQueryForm
 * Object via the POST body.
 */
```

Does it mean that, even through a HTTPS connection, the JSON form would be sent in plaintext (i.e. not encrypted) if we use [HttpMethod.GET](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/ApiMethod.HttpMethod)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  What that means is that this method (whatever it is) is used to retrieve data from the server in response to a request from the client.  Normally, when a client is just asking for something, it should use an HTTP GET.  HTTP POST requests are intended for sending data *to* the server.

However, in this case, the client wants to send a (potentially large) object (called `conferenceQueryForm`) to the server to describe what it wants.  That may be too big or cumbersome to do using a GET request, so instead they've used POST.